# MarkerCluster with GeoJSON weird representation

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, markerclusterer

Here is my script, sorry if it's a bit messy, I've tried alot...

```
<script>
     var geojsonObject = #{jsonDataModel.jsonData};

     var markerIcon = L.icon({
         iconUrl: '#{request.contextPath}/images/pin48.png',
         iconAnchor:   [17,43] // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
         });

      <!--Initialisieren der Karte mit Angabe der Koordinate und der Zoomstufe:-->
      var mapLat = #{jsonDataModel.centerLat};
      var mapLon = #{jsonDataModel.centerLon};
      var zoom = #{jsonDataModel.zoom};
        var map = L.map('map').setView([mapLat, mapLon], zoom);

        <!--Laden eines Layers mit Angabe der URL auf den OpenStreetMap-Kartendienst sowie einem Kartenlabel:-->
        L.tileLayer(#{geodataserverurlreader.geodataserverUrl}, {
            attribution: '&amp;copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap-Mitwirkende</a>. ',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

        L.tileLayer('http://a.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: 'Daten <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">© OpenStreetMap-Mitwirkende</a>, Grafik: <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA 2.0</a> <a href="http://www.openrailwaymap.org/">OpenRailwayMap</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 10,
        }).addTo(map);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.openrailwaymap.org/standard/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
            attribution: 'Daten <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">© OpenStreetMap-Mitwirkende</a>, Grafik: <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA 2.0</a> <a href="http://www.openrailwaymap.org/">OpenRailwayMap</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

        var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

        var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(geojsonObject, {
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer : function(feature, latlng){
               var marker = L.marker(latlng);
//             oms.addMarker(marker);
               return marker;
            }
            });

        markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

        map.addLayer(markers);

  </script>
```

So now I'm wondering what I'm missing:

1. I've added the `tileLayer` to the map.
2. I initialized the `markerCluster`.
3. I'm (hopefully) adding the geoData properly to the Layer (`geoJsonLayer`)
4. I add these layers to the `markerCluster`.
5. I add the markerCluster to the map.

Additionally, I made sure my leaflet script is **before** the markercluster.

```
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/lib/leaflet/leaflet-src.js" />
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/lib/leaflet/leaflet.markercluster-src.js" />

<script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/oms.js" />
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/js/oneachfeature.js" />
```

My result looks like this:
[image: weird lines and stuff]

(These lines came with adding the 3rd `L.tileLayer`

Anyone got an Idea what I'm doing wrong?

## GeoData

```
{  
   "totalFeatures":2,
   "features":[  
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               10.111521,
               54.3688972
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>: 928012610566 / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 03.11.2011 09:20:00"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               9.9738655,
               53.4957533
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>: 928012610368 / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 03.10.2011 09:00:17"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               11.4343346,
               50.5976445
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>:  / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 01.06.2011 09:07:30"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               11.3753961,
               50.6505401
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>:  / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 05.08.2010 10:00:12"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               9.9325934,
               53.5313402
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>: 928012610376 / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 06.08.2012 14:56:23"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               9.6329706,
               53.7676329
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>:  / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 05.08.2010 14:51:40"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               9.6329706,
               53.7676329
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>:  / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 05.08.2010 14:51:40"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               8.2252779,
               53.1435944
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>: 928012650174 / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? STOERCODE ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 06.06.2017 15:16:11"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               8.7582774,
               51.7287785
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>: 928012650166 / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 06.06.2017 15:44:46"
         }
      },
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               11.4343346,
               50.5976445
            ],
            "type":"Point"
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "popupContent":"<b>Fz/Tz<\/b>:  / <br><b>Auslösungsart<\/b>: ?? ZEIT ??<br><b>Code<\/b>: <br><b>Text<\/b>: <br><b>Ereigniszeit<\/b>: 01.06.2011 09:07:30"
         }
      }
    .
    .
    .

   ],
   "type":"FeatureCollection"
}
```

***VALID JSON (RFC 4627)***

Even testing my geojson data with geojson.io gives me valid markers. (can't link because my rep is too low.)

## Expected Result

Here is the wanted [result](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html).

Comment: First you should make sure you explain what is your expected result. Then sharing a sample of your `geojsonObject` would surely help. See [Asking MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a general rule.

Comment: @ghybs please take a look now.. :/

Comment: Which versions of Leaflet and Leaflet.markercluster do you use? Have you checked your browser console for potential messages?

Comment: Cross-posted in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255498/openstreetmap-marker-cluster-unwanted-representation